# JSON.parse() returns Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: jquery

String passes fine when I remove the double quotes at either end and pass it through an online parser. But when I try to use JSON.parse i get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

```
responseText: "{"session_id": "AAAAAAABvgm8szOYtCcbQg"}"
JSON.parse(responseText);
```

Comment: Look at the quotes you're using and how they've broken the syntax highlighting

Comment: Sorry Im not sure I follow your meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a string between single quotes in javascript to prevent having to escape them:

```js
responseText = '{"session_id": "AAAAAAABvgm8szOYtCcbQg"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(responseText));
```

Otherwise you should escape them when they are in the content:

```js
responseText = "{\"session_id\": \"AAAAAAABvgm8szOYtCcbQg\"}";
console.log(JSON.parse(responseText));
```

Comment: This is a server response so I can't change the text. Unless I str.replace it before parsing it.

Comment: what's the exact response you get?

Comment: response: "{"session_id": "AAAAAAABvieaPSlzg8ybow"}"
responseText: "{"session_id": "AAAAAAABvieaPSlzg8ybow"}"

Comment: It's really strange you don't get a valid json. Then yes, you should perform some transformations to get a valid object from it.